# Ember.js: Add subroute to existing route

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember-cli addon that creates routes.  In the addon, I expose a `configureRouter` function that should be called by the application that is using the addon.  In the application's `router.js`, in the `map()` callback, I call `configureRouter`, passing `this`.  This works fine, no issues.

Now, in my application (not the addon), I need to add a sub-route to one of the routes that was created by the addon.  As an example, the addon `configureRouter` function does something like this:

```
configureRouter(router) {
    router.route('a', function() {
      this.route('b');
    });
}
```

So that configures the route `a.b`.  Now, back in the main application, I need to add the route `a.b.c`.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1):

well, you could expose another callback for this:

```
configureRouter(router, cb) {
  router.route('a', function() {
    cb.apply(this, 'a');
    this.route('b', function() {
      cb.apply(this, 'b');
    });
  });
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
configureRouter(this, function(route) {
  if(route === 'b') {
    this.route('c');
  }
}
```

however I dont recommend this! What I would recommend is to drop the `configureRouter` entirely. When you install your addon I would use blueprints to inject the routes into the router (like `ember generate route` does). This allows the user to do any kind of customization he want.

If you dont expose more then a dozend routes I hardly doubt that your `configureRouter` method has any benefit. While it requires your user to may modify its router when upgrading, it also is much more explicit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  The addon is used in our corporate back-office applications and is shared across different apps.  The addon is responsible for a fairly complex set of routes and their setup is important for the links in the addon to work correctly.  However, a generic route extension mechanism similar to what you suggested is a good idea.